# jQuery 17104403............ was not called

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to call a web service placed in my local system. 
Facing an error alert of jQuery 17104403..... was not called.
I am using the following code : 
`

```
jQuery.support.cords = true;
    jQuery.ajax
    ({
        type:"GET",
        url:"http://(localhost)/leave/src/login.php?data={%22username%22:%22"+username+"%22,%22password%22:%22"+password+"%22}",    
        dataType:"jsonp",
        success : function(data)
        {   
                alert(data.username);
            alert(data.password);
        },
        error:function(xhr, textStatus, error) 
        {
            alert("Error: " + error);
        }
    });
```

`

This web service is calling data from a remote machine.
I'll be thankful if any help

Comment: Why the hyphens around `localhost`?

Comment: I suspect that the service isn't jsonp.

Comment: stackoverflow not allowing to write localhost so i have to put that in them.

Comment: yes the serivce is php but its outcome is coming in the form of json. It might be a case that it is not following the proper json format.

Comment: The outcome should be in jsonp not json since your dataType is jsonp.

Comment: I have converted the datatype to json but now its not showing the same error but the error sustains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsonp != json.

Natively jquery ajax jsonp implementation adds a `callback` parameter. You can override the name of this parameter with setting the `jsonp` ajax property and the value of this parameter with setting the `jsonpCallback` ajax property.

In case you provide your own callback name, it has to be accessible from the global scope.

Of course: server side, you will have to use the jsonp callback name to surround the generated json content with the call of the given function.

**EDIT**

Admit your json response was `{}` and the callback parameter is given with `?callback=jQuery1234567890` then your server should answer `jQuery1234567890({})`

Comment: let jQuery add this callback parameter for you and concentrate on the server side code, if you have access to it. Otherwise if it's a cross origin request, that means you cannot request it.

Comment: Running the url in the browser is not ajax. If the server is not on the same domain you have to handle jsonp or set `Access-control-allow-origin` header to `*`.